# Why doesn't array.push() work when looping object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-push

I'm doing a simple Sudoku solver with JavaScript, and there is one problem with adding new values to array. My script makes random length arrays in for..in loop. I have tested this script with Chrome Debugger, and there I see that it loops right count. Did I missed some important point of JS objects, or is the .push() wrong way to do this kind of thing?

```
this.areaSize = gridSideSize * gridSideSize;

//On progress -data structures
this.structures = 
{ 
    rows: new Array(),
    columns: new Array(),
    parents: new Array()
};

//Fill the data structures with the area object
for(var struct in this.structures)
{
    for(var a = 0; a < this.areaSize; a++)
    {
        var tmp = new PartialArea(this.areaSize);
        this.structures[struct].push(tmp);
    }
    console.log(struct.length);
}
```

Console tells me, that the first array is 4 items long and the second and the third one are 7 items long.

Comment: Just log `struct` instead of `struct.length`. You’ll notice your error immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct` are the *property names* `rows` (which is a *string* of length 4), `columns` (7) and `parents` (7).

Logging `this.structures[struct].length` would give the expected results.